# Not able to receive Platform Event in Salesforce1 App

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforce1-app, platform-event

I have created Lightning Component to receive Platform Event using lightning:empApi component and Its working fine.

But when i am adding that component in Navigation Item for Salesforce1 app. It is not receiving event data. In salesforce [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation) mentioned that it will work with Salesforce Mobile App.

Can someone please let me know if it is possible?

Comment: What's your Navigation Item API version?

Comment: I am taking about Mobile Navigation. As per my knowledge there is no any API version we have to specify for Mobile Navigation item.